# How to use AWS S3 policies to enforce ownership of resources for federated users?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, boto

I'm writing an app where I have a set of users, and each user will have a number of files associated with them in a 'directory' within an S3 bucket.  Users will be authenticating using Amazon's STS, getting temporary security credentials that should allow them to access resources they own while not allowing them to access resources they do not (*think: "home" directories*).

Assuming the user already exists in the system (and is authenticated), and their file bucket is created (without a specified policy or ACL) using the naming scheme:

```
<< my app's bucket>>/<< user's identifier >>/
```

During a request for a user accessing file, we grant temporary security credentials as follows using boto:

```
get_federation_token(<< user's identifier >>, duration,policy=user_policy)
```

where user_policy is:

```
user_policy =  (r'{"Statement": [{"Effect":"Allow",
    "Action":[
"s3:PutObject",
"s3:GetObject",
"s3:GetObjectVersion",
"s3:DeleteObject",
"s3:DeleteObjectVersion"],
    "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::/%s/*"}]}' % (<< user's identifier >>))
```

I had thought I understood policies, but apparently I'm missing something.  Using the above scheme, I'm able to get/put resources under the user's directory, but also the directories/resources belonging to other users.  For the life of me, I can't get access properly segregated.  I've played with bucket policies as well, but that didn't bear fruit.

Any direction would be appreciated.

*Note: I'm stuck using STS, as we'll likely have too many users to create/use IAM users.*

Comment: Someone asked a question like this - it turned out that the bucket had a global public read set on it using a bucket policy. Make sure that there are no other ACLs, etc that allow access. Also it looks like there is no 'listing' access - is that what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone asked a question like this - it turned out that the bucket had a global public read set on it using a bucket policy. Double check that there are no other ACLs, etc that allow access. Also it looks like there is no 'listing' access - is that what you want? Can you call get on a bucket and get a listing of all files in it? (You should not be able to do this).

Don't know if this will help - they use "StringLike" in the policy.
http://www.techtricky.com/amazon-s3-how-to-restrict-user-access-to-specific-folder-or-bucket/

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/search.jspa?objID=f76&q=stringlike&x=0&y=0